# Putting elements in an array from for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a function that gets the `courseContentId` I wanted to put them all in an array from for loop but what happens is it creates a new array for every `courseContentId`. Here is my code.

```
function keyLoop() {
    let content = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list;
    content.forEach(a => {
        let cid = a.courseContentId;
        if (cid == undefined) {
            cid = ' ';
        }

        vm.loopKey = cid;
        var pass = vm.loopKey;
        result(pass);
    });

    function result(pass) {
        let receiver = [];

        receiver.push(pass);
        console.log(receiver);
    }
}
```

I wanted them to be like this [471, 471, 471, 472, 472, 472, 473, 473 ....]

But instead it returns [471] [471] [471] [472] ...... and so on.

Comment: The receiver list is recreated every time you call result... put its definition outside of the function result()

Comment: `let receiver = [];` is making a new array.... So if you do not want a new array than do not define a new one.

Comment: make let receiver = []; as a  global variable. Means bring it out of the result function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
 function keyLoop() {
    let content = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list;
    let receiver = [];
    content.forEach(a => {
        let cid = a.courseContentId;
        if (cid == undefined) {
            cid = ' ';
        }

        vm.loopKey = cid;
        var pass = vm.loopKey;
        receiver.push(pass);
    });
    console.log(receiver);
}
```

Comment: It returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are defining a new empty array each time you call the result function.

In order to do this, you'll want to create the array, before your loop executes.

```
function keyLoop() {
    let receiver = [];
    let content = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list;
    content.forEach(a => {
        let cid = a.courseContentId;
        if (cid == undefined) {
            cid = ' ';
        }

        vm.loopKey = cid;
        var pass = vm.loopKey;
        result(pass);
    });

    function result(pass) {
        receiver.push(pass);
        console.log(receiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
function keyLoop() {
    let content = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list;
    let receiver = [];
    let courseCounter = 0;

    content.forEach(a => {
        let cid = a.courseContentId;
        if (cid == undefined) {
            cid = ' ';
        }

        vm.loopKey = cid;
        var pass = vm.loopKey;
        receiver[courseCounter] = pass;
        courseCounter++;
    });
    console.log(receiver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want just to sort the list?

```
let result = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list.map(v => v.courseContentId).sort();
```

Here we are taking a list of ids (by .map) and sorting them. If we want to protect the result from undefined ids, it may look like

```
let result = vm.comparisonThumbnail.list
  .map(v => Number(v.courseContentId))
  .filter(v => !isNaN(v))
  .sort();
```

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks